# Solve for $m$ in $d^m = n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I believe the answer is $m = \lceil \sqrt[d]n \rceil$ or  $\lfloor \sqrt[d]n \rfloor$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you heard of logarithms?

Comment: ahahah this made me laugh, what apositive community!

Comment: That is the danger of written communication. My comment was merely a question to get the exchange started, but if read as a sarcastic comment regarding your mathematical knowledge it may seem a bit harsh, I agree :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any logarithm $\log$, we have
$$\log n = \log (d^m) = m \log d,$$
so $$m = \frac{\log n}{\log d} = \log_d n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Try using logarithms. A logarithm is defined as follows,
If $a^{b}=c$, then $\log_{a} c=b$
So, similarly, here we get
$m=\log_{d} n$.
We can further simplify it by changing the logarithms' base to $10$,
$m=\frac{\log_{10} n}{\log_{10} d}$
If you want to learn more about logarithms, go [here](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)